Minimizing KL-divergence against un-normalized probability distribution
Let $\Delta_n$ denote the $n$-dimensional simplex, ie. $\Delta_n \equiv \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n_+ : \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1 \right\}$. I have a strictly positive (component-wise) vector $w \in \mathbb{R}^n_+$ and I'd like to show
$$x^* \in \underset{x \in \Delta_n}{\arg \min} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \ln \left\{ \frac{x_i}{w_i} \right\} \implies x^*_i = \frac{w_i}{\lVert w \rVert_1}$$
Intuitively, to minimize the KL-divergence between $x \in \Delta_n$ and an un-normalized probability distribution $w \in \mathbb{R}^n_+$ we take $x$ to be a scaled version of $w$.
I've been looking at the Lagrangian
$$\mathcal{L}(x, \lambda) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \ln \left\{ \frac{x_i}{w_i} \right\} + \lambda \left( 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right)$$
with partials
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x_i} = 1 + \ln \left\{ \frac{x_i}{w_i} \right\} - \lambda x_i$$
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \lambda} = 1 - \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i$$
but setting them to zero doesn't lead me to an obvious next step.

Using log-properties and that $\sum_i x_i = 1$ it follows that
\begin{align}
   \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \ln\left ( \frac{x_i}{w_i} \right ) 
   &= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \ln\left ( \frac{x_i}{w_i/\|w\|_1} \cdot\frac{1}{\|w\|_1}\right ) \\
   &= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\ln \left ( \frac{x_i}{w_i/\|w\|_1} \right ) - x_i\ln(\|w\|_1) \\
   &= -\ln(\|w\|_1) + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\ln \left ( \frac{x_i}{w_i/\|w\|_1} \right )
\end{align}
The last equality is where it is used that $\sum_i x_i = 1$. The latter expression is minimized by setting $x_i = \frac{w_i}{\|w\|_1}$ as you expected.

Sorry how do you know the minimizer of the latter expression? It seems to be the same as the original problem except with a different constant in the denominator.

The last expression is the KL-Divergence between $x$ and $w/||w||_1$ and the KL-divergence is always non-negative. Setting $x_i = w_i/||w||_1$ achieves the lower bound of zero.

My partial was wrong. It should have been
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x_i} = 1 + \ln \left( \frac{x_i}{w_i} \right) - \lambda = 0 \implies x_i = w_i e^{\lambda - 1}$$
and then
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \lambda} = 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 0 \implies 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n w_i e^{\lambda - 1} = 0 \implies e^{\lambda - 1} = \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i}$$
and we conclude
$$x_i = \frac{w_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i} = \frac{w_i}{\lVert w \rVert_1}$$
